# Swipe contents in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I am working with android. I am working to create a swipeable XML  with 3 layers, each layer can be swipe separately. At a time only one app with its image and description and also a button for download must view in my each layer. when I swipe each layer, next contents will load at the positions. Is it possible with view pager?

Comment: Yes it is possible with view pager..

Comment: how to change the contents in each swipe??

Comment: your adapter handle that, see http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Comment: But it needs separate xml file need for each swipe.. ryt??

Comment: try this link  http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/

Comment: no, you can use with separate or same `xml` layout